# Formula Fields issue character limit

Tags: formula-field

I have Created 2 formula fields.

1. TestFormula1__c
2. TestFormula2__c

- TestFormula1__c field is of number datatype with zero decimal places
- TestFormula2__c field is of text datatype.
  I am referring 1st formula field in 2nd formula field.

### TestFormula1__c

```
IF(OR(ISPICKVAL(Status,'Draft'),ISPICKVAL(Status,'Hold'),ISPICKVAL(Status,'NEW')),null, IF(ISBLANK(Start_Date5__c),0,IF(ISBLANK(End_Date5__c),(Now()-Start_Date5__c),(End_Date5__c- Start_Date5__c))) +

IF(ISBLANK(Start_Date4__c),0,IF(ISBLANK(End_Date4__c),(Now()-Start_Date4__c),(End_Date4__c- Start_Date4__c))) +

IF(ISBLANK(Start_Date3__c),0,IF(ISBLANK(End_Date3__c),(Now()-Start_Date3__c),(End_Date3__c- Start_Date3__c))) +

IF(ISBLANK(Start_Date2__c),0,IF(ISBLANK(End_Date2__c),(Now()-Start_Date2__c),(End_Date2__c- Start_Date2__c))) +

IF(ISBLANK(Start_Date1__c),0,IF(ISBLANK(End_Date1__c),(Now()-Start_Date1__c),(End_Date1__c- Start_Date1__c))))
```

### TestFormula2__c

```
IF(NOT(OR(ISPICKVAL(Status,'Draft'),ISPICKVAL(Status,'Hold'),ISPICKVAL(Status,'NEW'))),CASE(TestFormula1__c,
0,$Label.test1,
1,$Label.test2,
2,$Label.test3,
3,$Label.test4,
4,$Label.test5,
5,$Label.test6,
6,$Label.test7,
$Label.test8),null)
```

### My issue is when i try to execute, i am not getting specified values in which i mentioned in CASE function. (eg: for 0 i am not able to see the label values which i mentioned in $Label.test1).
I debugged the issue as follows:

1.Removed whole formula in TestFormula2__c and replaced the existing formula with TEXT(TestFormula1__c), then i observed that this TestFormula2__c field is returning some decimal values.
In order to remove the decimals i tried using FLOOR() to the formula then i ran into the 5000 characters limit error.

Can someone help me in resolving the above issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A formula with zero decimal places doesn't round to zero decimal places, it only displays zero decimal places (e.g. 0.1 displays as 0 in the UI, but still counts as 0.1 when used in another formula).

In addition, including one formula inside another adds *at least* the compiled size of the first formula to the second formula. As a result, it's really easy to hit the 5K compiled limit.

Every use of a field counts for the full size in a formula; reduce the number of field occurrences to reduce compiled size.

You might try this:

```
IF(
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL(Status,'Draft'),
        ISPICKVAL(Status,'Hold'),
        ISPICKVAL(Status,'NEW')
    ),
    null,
    FLOOR( 
        IF(ISBLANK(Start_Date5__c), 0, BLANKVALUE(End_Date5__c, NOW())-Start_Date5__c) +
        IF(ISBLANK(Start_Date4__c), 0, BLANKVALUE(End_Date4__c, NOW())-Start_Date4__c) +
        IF(ISBLANK(Start_Date3__c), 0, BLANKVALUE(End_Date5__c, NOW())-Start_Date3__c) +
        IF(ISBLANK(Start_Date2__c), 0, BLANKVALUE(End_Date2__c, NOW())-Start_Date2__c) +
        IF(ISBLANK(Start_Date1__c), 0, BLANKVALUE(End_Date1__c, NOW())-Start_Date1__c)
    )
)
```

If that's not enough, you might try:

```
IF(
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL(Status,'Draft'),
        ISPICKVAL(Status,'Hold'),
        ISPICKVAL(Status,'NEW')
    ),
    NULL, 
    FLOOR(
        MAX(0, BLANKVALUE(End_Date5__c, NOW())-BLANKVALUE(Start_Date5__c, NOW())) +
        MAX(0, BLANKVALUE(End_Date4__c, NOW())-BLANKVALUE(Start_Date4__c, NOW())) +
        MAX(0, BLANKVALUE(End_Date5__c, NOW())-BLANKVALUE(Start_Date3__c, NOW())) +
        MAX(0, BLANKVALUE(End_Date2__c, NOW())-BLANKVALUE(Start_Date2__c, NOW())) +
        MAX(0, BLANKVALUE(End_Date1__c, NOW())-BLANKVALUE(Start_Date1__c, NOW()))
    )
)
```

...

Or, one final optimization:

```
IF(
    1 = CASE(
        Status,
        'Draft', 1,
        'Hold', 1,
        'NEW', 1,
        0
    ),
    NULL, 
    FLOOR(
        MAX(0, BLANKVALUE(End_Date5__c, NOW())-BLANKVALUE(Start_Date5__c, NOW())) +
        MAX(0, BLANKVALUE(End_Date4__c, NOW())-BLANKVALUE(Start_Date4__c, NOW())) +
        MAX(0, BLANKVALUE(End_Date5__c, NOW())-BLANKVALUE(Start_Date3__c, NOW())) +
        MAX(0, BLANKVALUE(End_Date2__c, NOW())-BLANKVALUE(Start_Date2__c, NOW())) +
        MAX(0, BLANKVALUE(End_Date1__c, NOW())-BLANKVALUE(Start_Date1__c, NOW()))
    )
)
```

I'm not sure we can get any more optimized than this.

Comment: Thank u précised formula worked. @sfdcfox